# Is running gradle via android studio different from via Terminal ？

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

When i ran Gradle task via Android Studio' GUI (using IDE‘s own Gradle distribution), no dependencies need to download. But after that, when i did the same via terminal the first time, it would download some dependencies, for example, "lint" . Is it normal ? I don't want to cache two duplicated dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't want to cache two duplicated dependencies.

Gradle (and Maven) dependencies are only contained within your user home folder, in `.gradle` and `.m2` respectively. Unless you have modified those files otherwise, of course.

Gradle just happens to be included in Android Studio. If you are able to run Gradle independently in the terminal, then you have two installations of Gradle.

The gradle wrapper would be downloaded separately of the local system installation.

> for example, "lint"

Lint shouldn't be downloading anything. It only inspects your code for errors and warnings.

Comment: When i click "tasks" in Android Studio, the task complete quickly and no dependencies need to download. After that, I ran "./gradlew tasks" in the project directory, it would downlowd dependencies, including google's lint (jar).  I don't know whether Android Studio's Gradle distribution share the same cache directory with my local Gradle distribution. I don't know whether gradle running in bash is aware of Android SDK.

Comment: Gradle shouldn't need to be aware of the Android SDK because Gradle isn't only used by Android, it can compile and build many different programming languages.

Comment: I think maybe the the Gradle distribution shipped with Android Studio use different cache directory. I have configured Android Studio to use the local distribution of Gradle. It works fine. Forgive my poor English grammer.